# How to generate bundle with native code with Android Studio correctly?

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, google-play, java-native-interface

I am trying to publish an Android application with Android Studio's `Generate Signed Bundle or APK` (choosing bundle) feature.

At first, I was getting native crashes and was trying to investigate them. To do this, I was trying to publish a symbol table and was playing with the `Android Studio` version, changing it from `4.0.1` and `4.1 RC`. Also, I was playing with `Gradle Plugin` and `Gradle` versions.

After that I suddenly found, that native crashes have gone. I didn't change any line of code, only minor `Android Studio` settings, plugins upgrade, and `Gradle` scripts.

Also, I found, that one of my published (for testing) versions also cause crash on my physical device, although I didn't have any when debugging.

Apparently, the native code I was sending to my device via USB cable is not the same, that the one have reached the very same device via Google Play.

How can this happen? How can I control the process of binary code generation so hard that it can turn from crashing to no crashing and back?

Comment: I don't see how this implies any bugs in Google Play or the Developer Console(?). It seems like the way forward if you want to investigate this further would be to rebuild with the same exact tools as you were using before, so that you can A) get symbolized crashes, and B) perhaps also compare the old and new binaries.

Comment: @Michael I don't know; how one can explain crashes in other way?

Comment: There are a lot of details missing from your question, so all we can do is speculate, but I can see several reasons for this behavior: Perhaps the crash only happens occasionally and you've been lucky so far with the new version. Perhaps you're not testing on the exact same devices under the exact same conditions. Perhaps one of the tools you updated results in some change in the build settings for native code.

Comment: @Michael now I found, that the code is crashing on the same device if passed via google play.

Comment: Your native code is probably relying on undefined behavior such as using uninitialized memory or writing past some allocation somewhere. The fact that it manifests at different times on different devices is a tell-tale sign. Look at the crash reports and figure out what went wrong.